# Norm of infinite dimensional Hilbert space to calculate difference between string lengths

Tags: hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

I am trying to wrap my head around Proposition 13, last para, page 1049 in [this paper](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume5/cortes04a/cortes04a.pdf). The authors are trying to prove certain properties of string *edit distance* (defined at the start of Section of 6.1): the minimal cost of a series of edit operations (symbol insertions, deletions, or substitutions) transforming one string into the other, where the cost of each edit operation is 1.

The edit distance between two strings $x,y$, each from the vocabulary $\Sigma$, so that $x,y \in \Sigma^*$, is denoted by $d_e(x,y)$.

Now this is what the authors are claiming: if the vocabulary has exactly one symbol, i.e. $|\Sigma|=1$, then $d_e(x,y)$ is the difference of lengths of strings $x$ and $y$ (I get this). A string $x \in \Sigma^∗$ can be viewed as a vector of the Hilbert space $\mathbb{R}^\infty$. Denote by $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ the corresponding norm. Then for all $x,y \in \Sigma^*$, $d_e(x,y)=\lVert x-y \rVert$.

This last bit is what I need help with. What space has a norm that can measure the difference in string lengths?

If I naively assume that in the projection, the $i^{th}$ dimension represents the presence/absence of a symbol at the $i^{th}$ place (so that $x,y$ are essentially bit vectors), then the standard norm (=$L_2$) gives me the square root of the difference in lengths. This is not $d_e(x,y)$.

Any help appreciated!